# Translating single-word commands

Tags: translation

(I know it's a poor title, but I cannot word it properly. If someone has an idea on what I'm asking about, please edit it)

How should words such as "like", "comment", "share", "upvote", etc. be translated, what verb ending is appropriate? What I mean by that is should e.g. Facebook "like" button translated as ŝati, ŝatu, (mi) ŝatas? I've noticed that using the infinitive is the most popular option, but I'd like some confirmation whether is it correct - in my personal opinion, infinitive feels wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your examples look like labels for buttons instructing the program to do something on your behalf. It is generally felt that *-i* is best: *ŝati, komenti, kunhavigi, voĉdoni pore* etc.

The idea is that you are saying to yourself *Mi volas...* or *Mi intencas...*

This convention helps the user to tell the difference between what they can *choose* to do, and what they *must* do for the program to proceed. That distinction is not visible if *-u* is used for both.

Comment: Probably best to read the discussion here before concluding what is generally felt to be best.  http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/verbs-of-buttons-on-websites/1169#1169

Comment: That's just the same link I gave above...

Comment: Jes ja! Kompreneble.