# Se mi tradukus "delete", ĉu mi uzus "forigu" aŭ "forigi"?

Tags: verbs

Se mi tradukus "delete (this message)" el la angla al Esperanto, ĉu mi uzus *forigu* aŭ *forigi*?

Comment: Look at a [previous discussion](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/verbs-of-buttons-on-websites). Having said for me it feels really strange to ask the computer/system to do something [_(Bonvolu) Krei dosierujon_ ], while the system commands me [_Elektu…_]. I prefer the contrary: the system asks me and I command it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oni kutime uzas la verbojn ĉi tiel kiam oni tradukas komputilajn programojn.

Por ordonoj al la komputilo, ekzemple en menuoj, uzu la infinitivon:

- "Serĉi denove"
- "Krei dosierujon"
- "Konservi la pasvorton"

Por ordonoj al la uzantoj, uzu la imperativon:

- "Bonvolu tajpi vian pasvorton denove"
- "Elektu vian preferatan lingvon"
- "Ne uzu la x-sistemon"

Do por respondi vian demandon: prefere uzu "forigi", ĉar la komputilo faru tion.

Comment: Ankaŭ en mozilla oni faras tion: https://mozilla-l10n.github.io/styleguides/eo/