# "Ŝargo de X" aŭ "Ŝargas X"?

Tags: translation, information-technology

Mi tradukas programeton, kaj la frazo "Loading messages" tradukis al "Ŝargo de mesaĝoj". Al mi, ĝi aŭdas malĝuste... Mi tradukus "Ŝargas mesaĝojn". Kiu frazo estas ĝusta, kaj kial?

Answer (score 1):

En Mozilla, laŭ la [Ĝeneralaj reguloj pri tradukoj](https://mozilla-l10n.github.io/styleguides/eo/) (vidu *sensubjektaj verboj*) ni uzas:

```
Mesaĝoj ŝargataj
```

aŭ

```
Ŝargado de mesaĝoj
```

Ĉi okaze *ŝargo de X* ne bonas, ĉar tiun agon oni nomas *ŝargado*.

En la esperanta, la nomo de (nedaŭra) ago ne ne estas tiel regula. Kelkfoje *-ado* estas deviga, kelkfoje ĝi ne devas aperi, kaj kelkfoje kaj *-o* kaj *-ado* esas akcepteblaj:

```
ŝargi - ŝargado
sendi - sendo
lavi - lav(ad)o
```

Bona vortaro klarigos la nomon de la ago por ĉiu verbo, ĉar ne ĉiam estas evidente).

Answer (score 0):

Mi preferas verbon ĉi-okaze kaj kun la verbo ŝargi laŭ [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#%C5%9Dargi) oni uzas rektan objekton, do *ŝargas mesaĝojn*. Eble valoras ankaŭ legi [antaŭan diskuton](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/verbs-of-buttons-on-websites) pri infinitivo kontraŭ imperativo en interfaco.

Comment: Kial la infinitivo? La mesaĝojn ŝargas nun. (Pardonu mian simplan lingvon)

Comment: Ha, mia eraro, vi pravas.

Comment: Sed tia traduko estus nenatura pro manko de subjekto

Comment: La subjekto, _la sistemo_ aŭ _la programo_, estas subkomprenata.