# How to label UI elements that "do" something?

Tags: information-technology

User interface elements that "do" something (such as buttons) are often labelled with verbs or phrases containing a verb:

> Save

Or, from this platform:

> Show formatting tips

> Review your question

In English it's impossible to tell whether they are in infinitive or in imperative, because both take the same form in modern English for most or maybe even all verbs.

It's also usually hard to distinguish whether the *user* performs the action with the help of the computer / the software (which would indicate towards infinitive, in my opinion) or whether the user orders *the computer / the software* to perform the action (which would clearly mandate imperative).

What is conventionally (or traditionally) used when labelling UI elements in Esperanto with verbs? Infinitivo or volitivo?

Comment: You might want to read [this discussion](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/verbs-of-buttons-on-websites/) here in Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the infinitive unless you need to user to do something:

```
Serĉi
Kopii
Alglui
Ignori supersignojn dum serĉo
```

but

```
Ŝanĝu viajn agordojn kaj provu denove
Retajpu vian pasvorton tiel ke ĝi enhavas ankaŭ ciferojn
Restartigu la programon por apliki tiujn ŝanĝojn
```

The [Style Guide for Esperanto](https://mozilla-l10n.github.io/styleguides/eo/#verboformoj) used for Mozilla products uses this.